# Practical challenges for microarray analysis and single cell

Tags: single-cell, microarray

currently, I am learning single-cell sequencing and microarray analysis. I am searching for somewhere (or any alternative way)to practice and get hands-on with these techniques. please help me with that.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please be more specific on which level of analysis you are planning to do. Are you looking for point-and-click graphical software or do you plan to construct your own workflows, and if yes, in which language?